# Dynamically creating WCF workflow (xamlx)

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, workflow-foundation-4, xamlx

I was trying to create workflows dyanamically in 4.0. I was trying to create xamlx files dyanamically and save in particular folder. I need to compile these files from a WCF service to generate the dlls. 
Will this be possible?
How does the xamlx files gets compiled to dll when we build the solution? is there anything similar to csc.exe which we used to compile c# files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to compile? A XAMLX is **not** compiled but used as is at runtime.

Comment: Thanks Maurice, So if i create a xamlx file outside VS, can i use that within in WCF Workflow service application.